# Move caret to start and end of line in a RichEditBox

Tags: c#, uwp, richeditbox

I've a RichEditBox that I'd like to add keyboard shortcut support to enable moving to the start or the end of the line that the caret is currently on. I've already figured out shortcuts supporting going to start or end of sentence as that involved simply reviewing the text value of the content and finding the nearest period. However, I believe what I'm looking for now is more involved as it requires working through the *raw* content of the file, which I'm not comfortable with nor have managed to find any resources with the guidance I'm after (I've mostly found answers on detecting the EOL character type rather than moving the caret to the EOL).

Comment: Have you seen this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No help unfortunately as that's a RichTextBox property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move caret, we can use the [`RichEditBox.Document.Selection.Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextrange#Methods_) method to move the insertion point forward or backward by the specified number of units.

We can set [`TextRangeUnit.Line`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.textrangeunit) to the `Move` method, it will move caret to start or end of line in a RichEditBox.

For example:

```
myRichEdit.Document.Selection.Move(TextRangeUnit.Line, 1);
```

Comment: Woah, didn't realise this existed. However, small problem - sometimes the caret moves to the end of the line, but other times to the start of the next line.

Comment: A single line of text on a display, provided that the display is associated with the range. If no display is associated with a range, `Line` is treated as `Paragraph`. It seems your line terminated by an end-of-paragraph mark, such as carriage return/line, feed (CR/LF), carriage return (CR), vertical tab(VT), line feed (LF), form feed (FF), or the Unicode paragraph separator (0x2029).